# Which package is needed to import vue components?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm new to nativescript and "npm-related" development development and trying to create my first NativeScript-Vue application, and have got some troubles.

1) First of all, when I use the `import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';` syntax instead of `const Vue = require('nativescript-vue');` I get such exception:

```
    An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application 
    com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 

    Cannot compile /data/data/org.nativescript.sirius/files/app/main.js

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.sirius/files/app/main.js, 
    line: 1, column: 67
```

2) When trying to import vue components(with .vue extension) they are not even being found..

```
    An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application 
    com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 

    Error calling module function 

    Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: 
    "./components/test", relative to: app/
```

I suppose I have some packages missing, but have no idea which exactly.

Here is my package.json:

```
    "nativescript": {
           "id": "org.nativescript.sirius",
            "tns-android": {
               "version": "5.2.1"
        }
     },
   "dependencies": {
           "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
           "nativescript-vue": "^1.3.1",
           "tns-core-modules": "^3.4.1"
    },
   "devDependencies": {}
```

Comment: Your dependencies seems pretty much old, the current `nativescript-vue` version is `v2.2.0` and `tns-core-modules` is on `v5.5.2`. Did you create your project form official starter templates?

Comment: I have NativeScript support plugin installed in WebStorm. v0.13.0

Comment: Manoj, thank you for giving me the clue. Looks like that plugin creates project template with legacy packages. I've created a new project using console 'tns create' command and everything seem to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies seems pretty much old, the current `nativescript-vue` version is `v2.2.0` and `tns-core-modules` is on `v5.5.2`.

Try using the official starter templates to create project via CLI.